# How can I auto-number math equations in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

```
$$
r  = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(X_i - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{S_xS_y}
$$
```

[The rendered equation is not numbered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEiLj.png)
Using \begin{aligned} and \end{aligned} generates an error.

I am also using knitr in RStudio, knitting to PDF using pandoc and xelatex engine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `align` not `aligned`

```
\begin{align}
    r  = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(X_i - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{S_xS_y}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. 
I was including $$...$$ and that seems to have been breaking things.

Comment: @Kranja Thanks for this comment. My difficulty was solved by omitting the `$$` and using `\begin{equation}...`. Evidently using both causes `! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.`

Answer (score 17):

As pointed out `amsmath` is already in the default template, so you can invoke the `equation` environment

```
\begin{equation}
y = mx+b
\end{equation}
```

This will automatically number equations in order of use. To use another character, say *,

```
\begin{equation}
\tag{*}
y = ax^2 + bx + c
\end{equation}
```

To leave equation unmarked simply leave `tag{}` blank.

For differences between `align` and `equation` see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation)

Comment: The `\usepackage{amsmath}` header in the YAML is what I was missing.

Comment: I added `\usepackage{amsmath}` header in the YAML and it worked whether it is included or not. 
My final code looks like this:
```
---
title: Test Doc
header_includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
output: pdf_document
---
\begin{align}
    r  = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(X_i - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{S_xS_y}
\end{align}

```

Comment: tarleb, thanks for the input. I was aware it was `header-includes` however with my every growing YAML for certain document types, changing from `header_includes` to `header-includes` broke the loading of other packages. Turns out this is because I do not need specify `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: So kranja, it is best not to specify `amsmath` and use `header-includes` not `header_includes` for loading other packages.

Comment: Thank you @jared-t 
This helps to clarify the sequencing - YAML and main body.