# How do I get amsmath to work in RMarkdown when knitting to PDF?

Tags: yaml, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, tinytex

In RMarkdown, I have a document I want to knit to pdf. The document has equations for which I need automatic numbering. I had been using the `$$ 1+1=2 \tag{1} $$` convention to write equations, but now want to switch to the `\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \eq:this_eq \end{equation}` convention so that I can have automatic numbering and easy cross referencing of the equations. The few online resources I've found make it seem like this should be fairly straightforward to do. For example [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stationery/vignettes/Rmarkdown.pdf) or [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations). However, I have run into no end of heartbreak in attempting to do it.

I am using version 3.4.3 with RStudio, the tinytex distribution, and have installed bookdown (which I am still not sure is really necessary to achieve my goal here). Here is a repex:

````
---
title: This title
author: "This guy"
date: "This date"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{amsmath}
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
    df_print: kable
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Calibri Light
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```
## Introduction

blah blah...

\begin{equation}
S = X \bar{P}
(\#eq:signals)
\end{equation}

## Later on

blah blah \@ref(eq:signals)
````

When I try to "knit to PDF" I am running into the error

```
! Package mathspec Error: `amsmath' must be loaded earlier than `mathspec'.
```

which has been reported as a bug and "fixed" [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85696/what-causes-this-strange-interaction-between-glossaries-and-amsmath), but I am unable to understand the fix or to follow its instructions. What I'm asking for is a set of really clear steps that will get me to where I can run the repex above without incident.

Some things I've tried:

The same error occurs when I replace `pdf_document` with `bookdown::pdf_document2`. Or when I remove

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{amsmath}
```

and instead put

```
includes:
  in_header: preamble.tex
```

after the line `latex_engine: xelatex`, where "preamble.tex" is a notepad file containing the line `\usepackage{amsmath}`

The comments in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939909/how-can-i-auto-number-math-equations-in-rmarkdown) seem to suggest that it is not even necessary to say anything about amsmath in the YAML options, which confuses me even more. When I remove any mention of amsmath from the YAML options, I get errors saying that the mathjax script is not recognized, for example:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \bar allowed only in math mode.
```

Answer (score 2):

For my problem, the solution came down to me just changing my latex engine from **xelatex** to **lualatex**. My document knit correctly and numbered my equations. For some reason, everywhere I looked they say one should use xelatex. Also I had `header-includes: - \usepackage{amsmath}` in the YAML header.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue. Thanks for the suggestions above. Here is what worked for me in the `output` and `header-includes` parts of the preamble:

```
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    latex_engine: lualatex

header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try your example, the equation is not labelled successfully.

Then I replace the output setting as `bookdown::pdf_book`. It works.

````
---
title: This title
author: "This guy"
date: "This date"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book
mainfont: Calibri Light
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Introduction

blah blah...

\begin{equation}
  S = X \bar{P}
  (\#eq:signals)
\end{equation}

## Later on

blah blah \@ref(eq:signals)
````