# RMarkdown: Auto Number Equations

Tags: latex, r-markdown

How can I autonumber equations in an Rmarkdown document?

I've tried including "\usepackage{mathajax}" in the header, but the equations won't autonumber.  I believe I need to configure mathjax, but can't figure out how.

I'm open to any solutions.

Please note, the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939909/how-can-i-auto-number-math-equations-in-rmarkdown) does not work.

Edit:

A simplified example of the desired output is below.

[image]

The code for the above image is below.  I tried using \begin{equation} and \end{equation} instad of "align";however, the HTML document does not output the formulas correctly.

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
output:
  html_document: default
---

\begin{align}
2+2 = 4 \tag{1} \\
3+2 = 5 \tag{2} \\
4+2 = 6 \tag{3} \\
5+2=7 \tag{4} \\
\end{align}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Among other things this would make clear what output format you are targeting.

Comment: @RalfStubner please see edited post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get pretty close by using `bookdown::html_document2`, c.f. [the documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations):

```
---
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---

\begin{align}
2+2 &= 4 \\
3+2 &= 5 (\#eq:three) \\
4+2 &= 6 (\#eq:four) \\
5+2 &= 7 (\#eq:five)
\end{align}
```

Result:

[image]

You get an equation number for every equation where you put a label. I have omitted the label on the first equation to show this effect. This is slightly different from the LaTeX's behavior, where you have to use `\notag` in an `align` environment to not get an equation number.